# K-Means and clustering

Tags: self-study, clustering, k-means

I am doing a course about machine learning this semester, and while reading a tutorial I came across this question:

[image]

\begin{align}
X &\sim U[0,d]  \\
N &\rightarrow \inf  \\
\delta &\rightarrow 0
\end{align}

I need to show that for k=2, the k-means algorithm convergent to the minimum of the square error. In the solution they wrote the following:

$$x^{(0)} = \frac{\mu^{(0)}_1+\mu^{(0)}_2}{2} = \alpha d  \tag{*}$$

where $\mu$ is the centroid  of a group $a$ between $[0, 1]$.

\begin{align}
\mu_1^{(1)} &= \frac{1}{2} \alpha d  \tag{*} \\
\mu_2^{(1)} &= \alpha d + \frac{}{2} = \frac{1+\alpha}{2}d  \tag{*}  \\
x^{(1)} &= \frac{\mu_1^{(1)}+\mu_2^{(1)}}{2} = \frac 1 2 \alpha d + \frac 1 4 d  \tag{*} \\
\\
\mu_1^{(n)} &= \frac 1 2 x^{(n-1)}  \tag{*}  \\
\mu_1^{(n)} &= \frac{x^{(n-1)}+d} 2  \tag{*}  
\end{align}

Can please explain me what they did in the starred equations?

The photo at the top is the question itself. As for the first starred equation, I thought that what they wrote means that given $\mu$ 1 and 2, $X$ will be approximately the average between them. $(n)$ means iteration number $n$. As for the lower set of starred equations, I don't understand how they calculated the centroids for every iteration from the definition of the centroid.

Comment: OK.
the first photo  is the question itself. As for the second photo, I thought that what they wrote means that given miu 1 and 2, X will be approximately the average between them.
(n) means  iteration number n.
as for the thirs photo,  i dont understand how from the definition of the centroid they calculated the centroids for every iteration. 
i hope its clear now

Comment: I edited your post to use the $\LaTeX$ formatting our site makes possible. Please ensure it still says what you want it to.

Comment: @gung delta meand the square , aka the distance between 2 points.